# How to detect what OS program is running on?

Tags: ocaml

I know there's `Sys.os_type` but it lumps OSX, Linux, etc. all under the same category. I'd like to detect the OS and most importantly distinguish between OSX and Linux.

Comment: It sounds more like a compile time switch than runtime thing. Have you considered that at all?

Comment: I have. Either approach could work but I'm not using optcomp or any other pre processor currently so I'd prefer not to introduce that unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
# let ic = Unix.open_process_in "uname" in
  let uname = input_line ic in
  let () = close_in ic in
  uname;;
- : string = "Darwin"
```

In OSX it returns "Darwin". In Linux it returns "Linux" (at least that's what I saw just now when I tried).

I don't know the behavior on Windows. But at least it will be different :-)